# Find the function $f(x)$ when it satisfies the ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

The Fourier transform of the function $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+xf(x)$ is $i[\frac{d}{dk}\widetilde{f}(k)+k\widetilde{f}(k)]$, so if a function $f(x)$ satisfies the ode $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+xf(x)=0$, then the Fourier transform will satisfy the same ode, that means that $f(x)$ and $\widetilde{f}(k)$ are described by the same functions.

Show that  in this case $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, $\widetilde{f}(k)=Ae^{-k^2}$. Calculate the value of the constant $A$.
$$$$
I have done the following so far:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+xf(x)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}f(x) \frac{1}{f(x)}=-x \Rightarrow ln|f(x)|=-\frac{x^2}{2}+c \text{ let } c=0, \Rightarrow  ln|f(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2} \Rightarrow f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

But I have to show that $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. What have I done wrong? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. Obviously,  $f(x) = \exp(-x^2)$ is not a solution as you can check easily.

Comment: Aha!! Ok!! And what's about $\widetilde{f}(k)$? Is there the solution $$\widetilde{f}(k)=A e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}$$??

Comment: yes indeed. {}{}

Comment: Ok!!! But why is there a constant $A$ at the formula of $\widetilde{f}(k)$ but not at the formula of $f(x)$?

Comment: You must keep the constant $c$. Then you get the constant $\pm e^c = A$ in front of the last expression.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why we take the constant of $f(x)$ equal to $1$?

Comment: No. THe idea here is to start from $f$, find the ode, take the Fourier transform, which shows that $\overline f$ is proportionnal to $f$. Then, you know what $\overline f(0)$ is!

Comment: I got stuck right now..Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: $\overline f(0)$ is the integral of $f$ on $\Bbb R$

Comment: And knowing the value of $\widetilde{f}(0)$ I can find the value of the constant $A$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar yes indeed.

Comment: Ok!!! Thanks a lot for your help!!! :-)